# How to lookup variables in the `conf/application.conf` in the Play Framework?

Tags: playframework

**Introduction**

According to [this documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.13/ProductionConfiguration#using-environment-variables) it should be possible to lookup environment variables within the `conf/application.conf`.

> **Using environment variables**
>
> You can also reference environment variables from your
>   application.conf file:
>
> ```
> my.key = defaultvalue
> my.key = ${?MY_KEY_ENV}
> ```
>
> Here, the override field my.key = ${?MY_KEY_ENV} simply vanishes if
>   there’s no value for MY_KEY_ENV, but if you set an environment
>   variable MY_KEY_ENV for example, it would be used.
>
> Because you can reference variables from within other variables,
>   ensure you don’t name your environmental variable the same as the
>   field name.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> MY_TOKEN = foo
> MY_TOKEN = ${?MY_TOKEN} # Will reference the previous line, NOT your environmentally set variable
> ```

**Attempt**

*docker-compose.test.yml*

```
sut:
  depends_on:
    - db
  ...
  environment:
    VAR_A: db:3306
```

*conf/application.conf*

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://${?VAR_A}/app"
```

**Problem**

For some reason it is not possible to lookup the variable: `${: Name or service not known`

```
sut_1  | [info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
sut_1  | [info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
sut_1  | [info] - should send 404 on a bad request *** FAILED ***
sut_1  | [info]   play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
sut_1  | [info]   at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
sut_1  | [info]   at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:806)
sut_1  | [info]   at 
...
sut_1  | [info]   Cause: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${: Name or service not known
sut_1  | [info]   at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
sut_1  | [info]   at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
sut_1  | [info]   at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
sut_1  | [info]   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
sut_1  | [info]   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
sut_1  | [info]   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
sut_1  | [info]   at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:190)
sut_1  | [info]   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297)
sut_1  | [info]   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2232)
sut_1  | [info]   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
sut_1  | [info]   ...
```

**Question**

How to lookup variables in the `conf/application.conf` in the Play Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclude variable out off string:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://"${?VAR_A}"/app"
```